# Prove that the intervals of the form $[a,b)$ are closed in the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the intervals of the form $[a,b)$ are closed in the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I manage to prove the statement by considering its complement, which is $\mathbb{R} \backslash [a,b)$. Then express it as union of open sets in lower limit topology.

My question is why $[a,b)$ is closed intuitively? Because when I first look at this, the interval $[a,b)$ is open in the lower limit topology.

Comment: To me the fact that the complement is pretty obviously open in the lower limit topology **is** an intuitive reason for the interval’s being closed.

Comment: @kahen: I just wish that the actor had spoken as clearly as Hitler did in his speeches — I caught only tiny bits of what he was actually saying!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: so in this topology, open sets are also closed sets and closed sets are also open sets?

Comment: Not in general, no. Sets of the form $[a,b)$ are both closed and open, as are finite unions of them, but $(0,1)$, for instance, is a set that is open but not closed, and $\Bbb Z$ is a set that is closed but not open.